# Show that every r-regular bipartite graph has a k-factorization if and only if k divides r

Tags: graph-theory

The idea with the return is to use that this graph has r perfect matchings, however, for the outward, I have no idea how to show that k divides r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An $r$-regular bipartite graph $G$ can be decomposed into $r$ disjoint perfect matchings.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $G$ has a $k$-factorization. Let there be $n$ such $k$-factors (clearly, $n$ is a positive integer). Since every vertex of $G$ has degree $k$ in each $k$ factor, and the $k$-factors are disjoint (this is a requirement for $k$-factorization), it follows that the union of the $k$ factors yields a graph whose vertices are all of degree $nk$ (i.e. it is $nk$-regular). But this union of these $k$-factors must yield $G$, which is $r$ regular. Hence $nk = r$, implying that $k$ divides $r$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let us do a $1$-factorization of $G$ (i.e. decompose it into $r$ perfect matchings). Then we can construct each of the $k$-factors in $G$'s $k$-factorization by taking the union of $k$ distinct one-factors. That is, if our one factors are $\{F_1, \cdots, F_r\}$, then we can construct the $k$-factors $\{K_1, K_2, \cdots, K_{r / k}\}$ by choosing 
$$K_j = F_{k(j - 1) + 1} \cup F_{k(j - 1) + 2} \cup \cdots \cup F_{kj}$$
for $1 \leq j \leq r / k$. Since $k$ divides $r$, we will be able to construct an integer number of $k$-factors without having any one-factors left over.